about "peewee_migrate"? I’ve encountered some issues
Here is the link to Open WebUI: https://github.com/open-webui/open-webui. I've searched through all the files but couldn't find how the files in open-webui/backend/apps/webui/internal/migrations were created. I only found that these files are being executed by the code router.run() in the open-webui/backend/apps/webui/internal/db.py file. I hope someone kind can help me find out how they were created.
I've searched through all the files, but I couldn't find how they were created. I hope someone can tell me how these files were generated.
